# How to put a label on the intersections points

Tags: graphics, labeling

I am really new to MATHEMATICA and I am struggling to make a nice graph as follows:

[image]

I am stuck a bit as I cannot put labels on  the intersection points....I do not want to use the drawing pallete as Microsoft Word has this option...
Maybe an option would be to use Epilog for better graphics but I do not really know how to do that...
labels with just the coords of the intersection points would be fine.
Thanks for any advise.

Comment: One pretty easy way is to use `ListPlot` with `Callout` or `Labeled` to generate the points with labels, e.g. `ListPlot[{Callout[{1, 2}, a], Callout[{3, 4}, b]}]`

Comment: @LukasLang, Thanks but shall I put this "ListPlot" expression inside the "ContourPlot" or do something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f1[x_, y_] := 2 x^2 - 3 y - 7
f2[x_, y_] := 3 x + 4 y + 1

cp = ContourPlot[{f1[x, y] == 0, f2[x, y] == 0}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -5, 50},
     PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 6}, All}];

intersections = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[cp];
```

You can add labels using `Epilog` + `Text`:

```
Show[cp, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Pane @ #, # + {1.7, .2}] & /@ intersections,
   PointSize[Large],  Red, Point /@ intersections}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `intersections` with `ListPlot`:

```
Show[cp, 
  ListPlot[intersections, 
    LabelingFunction -> (Callout[#, Right]&),
    PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, a lot for your answer. I could not imagine that mathematica  wants so much effort for just a label...